# gawk - sorting values from array of arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, gawk, percentile

Using gawk 4 to build arrays of arrays and need to figure out percentile data from it. Need to sort values in ascending order which doesn't appear possible using asort when working with multidimensional arrays. Some of my values will be duplicate integers, but I need to keep all duplicates.

Here is what my data looks like. Element names for [a] and [b] end up being unique strings. Array [b] then has elements that are named 1,2,3,etc and contain as values the data I need to sort on.

> ```
> mArray[a][b][1]=3456
> mArray[a][b][2]=1456
> mArray[a][b][3]=1456
> ...
> mArray[a][b][1]=9233
> mArray[a][b][2]=9233
> mArray[a][b][3]=1234
> ...
> mArray[a][b][1]=4567
> mArray[a][b][2]=4567
> mArray[a][b][3]=3097
> ```

I figure I can create regular arrays from each unique [a] element and insert values from it's corresponding [b][x] and then asort on that, but then I lose whatever duplicate values exist. Right now I am hacking it by walking mArray and writing to different files based on name of [a], printing out all values under [b][x] then running sort. Curious if there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Here is what I tried using asort against my mArray to test getting proper output. After 30mins I get no output or errors.

```
for ( a in mArray ) {
 for ( b in mArray[a] ) {
  n=asort(mArray[a][b][c])
  print n
 }
}
```

Background: parsing CSV reports from a network monitoring system, grabbing throughput sample data then aggregating those values across all interfaces to determine 95th percentile for total throughput of a device.

**Edit**

Desired output format after sorting would be:

> ```
> mArray[a][b][1]=1456
> mArray[a][b][2]=1456
> mArray[a][b][3]=3456
> .
> mArray[a][b][1]=1234
> mArray[a][b][2]=9233
> mArray[a][b][3]=9233
> ...
> mArray[a][b][1]=3097
> mArray[a][b][2]=4567
> mArray[a][b][3]=4567
> ```

Comment: consider editing your question to show the output you need, given the above input. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to sort myArray[a][b], not myArray[a][b][c], because c even doesn't exist ;)

If you don't want to sort in place, you have to add the destination as a second parameter to asort. At least this works in gawk, though I don't know since which version. In gawk 4 it does.

And then you have to print an array one by one...

```awk
for ( a in myArray ) {
 for ( b in myArray[a] ) {
  asort(myArray[a][b], n)
  for( i in n ) print "m["a"]["b"]["i"]="n[i]
 }
}
```

Comment: Oh, just saw how old this question is :D